# Adding a link to the top floating navigation in 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to add a feedback link to sharepoint pages. To make it stand out I would like to place it on the top floating navigation thats to the left of the user context menu (that contains links to my site and sign in as different user).

I am looking at altering the master page but the best I can do is place the link between the context menu and the developer dashboard link. I cannot seem to get it on the left side of user context menu.

I know I am messing with the master page and I am trying to find the best place in the tags to place it in. So I need help in whats the best place I can place it in.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the table using the css class "ms-globallinks", tie in a td next to the "Welcome User". We've used that in the same way you are using it and it works great. Make sure you are using SharePoint Designer, edit the masterpage and add a td along side of the globalright area. Add some code close to this:

```
<td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">
   <a href="http://yoursitehere.com" target="_blank">Submit Feedback</a>
</td>
```

Comment: I am looking at the v4.master in designer on the MasterPages root structure. I looked for "ms-gl" but could not find it. Am I in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look for this in the v4.master file:

you have a couple options:

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id=”PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource” runat=”server” />
```

The placement of the data source used to populate the left navigation bar.

and

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id=”PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop” runat=”server”/>
```

Top section of the left navigation bar.

You can try within those tags. For more detailed info on all the tags for masterpages you can check this out, Im sure youll find the right place :)

http://blog.allyis.com/working-with-sharepoint-2010-master-pages/

I would also like to note ms-globallinks is for 2007, i dont know about 2010. If your trying to put it within the welcome menu than i would highly recommend using a feature as its not ammending the main master page.

somthing like this:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Adding-items-to-the-user-welcome-menu-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

if you really want to do it in the master page using spd (sharepoint designer) you can follow this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/modify-the-default-master-page-HA010100906.aspx

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. This is not exactly what I have in mind. I am trying to get a link to show up at the very top navigation in between the site actions/folder tabs and the tab that has your username. I have played with the v4 master file and try as I might I cannot get the link to show up there. Then best I have been able to do is place it to the right. Which leads me to believe I need to use a special tag to get it right. I found out that beta versions of 2010 actually had that feedback link right there. I even have the script but no idea where on the v4 master page it was placed. Ill keep at it.